# How to make ML understand that (-) sign means "between numbers"?

Tags: classification

[image: age group]

When I try to work on this data error is thrown that non-numeric data can't be plotted. How can I make it identified by python that 25-29 means between 25 and 29 age?

Comment: Might be dirty but starting with  the mean could be usefull.

Comment: The most straight forward way to plot this would be a count plot of the age groups